# How can I version software components in Sparx Enterprise Architect (EA)?

Tags: components, uml, versioning, modeling, enterprise-architect

I am working at modelling a software system using Sparx Enterprise Architect 13. This system contains different versions of software components. We typically add services and/or APIs when we release a new version of a software component.

Currently, to reflect the fact that component ServiceV1 exposes an interface A and ServiceV2 exposes interfaces A (the same as ServiceV1) and B, I make ServiceV2 extend ServiceV1. But that is not straightforward:

- the generalization link is not available in diagrams between components, so I have to use Advanced > Parent...
- it lacks flexibility, because I cannot override interface A with a newer version of the interface

Is there a better way to do so? **What is the standard way of maintaining several versions of the same component?**

Thank you!

Comment: In fact, there are two questions here: (1) What is the standard way of maintaining several versions of the same component in UML? and (2) Is it possible to apply this in Enterprise Architect 13? -- I think this question would improve if part (2) would be omitted. If there is a solution in UML, then any UML tool should support it.

Comment: _I make ServiceV2 extend ServiceV1_ what is the rationale for that? Before, you explain that two components just expose the same interface. Is it that V2 is a successor of V1?

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl: I am interested in the standard UML way, then I am interested in knowing if it is achievable with EA13, which is the only tool I can use right now.

Comment: @qwerty_so: Exactly, ServiceV2 is the successor of ServiceV1 but both services coexist in my system. I have some devices running ServiceV1, some other exposing ServiceV2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is standardized by some standards body, but I would recommend to introduce two levels of abstraction: the unversioned component level and the versioned component level.

- On the unversioned component level, you have just a single element in the project repository for each component (not for each component version).
- On the versioned component level, you have a single element in the project repository *for each version of each component*.

Each versioned component, e.g. MyComponentV2 has a ≪trace≫ dependency to the unversioned    one, e.g. MyComponent.

To prevent unnecessary design work, you may decide to draw relationships between different components only between versioned component elements, not between unversioned component elements, or only vice versa. But this depends on the needs of your organization.

When you create a new version of a component, you copy the most recent version of the component (MyComponentV2) with all its connections, including the ≪trace≫-dependency to the unversioned component (MyComponent) and give it the right name (MyComponentV3).

I have applied this in a large project.

Comment: I think I will do this eventually if I find no other way, but I really would like to find a way that doesn't imply copy-pasting everything whenever I have an API change in one of my components. That's why I have tried using generalization links: at least it allows you to reuse the interfaces from the "parent" component.

Comment: If you have an API change in one of your components, then you would only apply that change to the latest version or in some cases to a few versions of that component, but not to whole lot of versions, would you?

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is no standard for modeling such a scenario. At best you can have conventions - which may differ from domain to domain. However, here's how I would model it:

[image]

`ServiceV2` has a `<<trace>>` relation to `ServiceV1`. UML 2.5.1 says on p. 682:

> «Trace» | Abstraction | Specifies a trace relationship between model elements or sets of model elements that represent the same concept in different models. Traces are mainly used for tracking requirements and changes across models. As model changes can occur in both directions, the directionality of the dependency can often be ignored. The mapping specifies the relationship between the two, but it is rarely computable and is usually informal.

So that should mean in this context ServiceV2 is created using ServiceV1 (I formerly used `<<derive>>` here since it seemed logical. But actually the UML semantic is defined differently; see p. 680 of UML 2.5.1). You could well invent your own stereotype here and explain it in the domain context (e.g. `<<version of>>`).

You would probably create a copy of ServiceV1 or model it manually as new element (you don't do that on a mass scenario, do you?). Here I added provided interfaces that both realize the common interface `A`. The quick linker does not offer those relations. You need to either go the clumsy Ctrl-I way or you grab the realization from the toolbox.

The `<<derive>>` dependency is not offered directly (unless you have your own MDG and defined it in QL or toolbox). So you create a dependency and choose `derive` from the stereotype menu.

---

This is a broad field and versioning is not as simple as just adding a numbering schema. In any case if you create a new component it will be something different. So the `<<derive>>` is probably the best option here.

Comment: ≪derive≫ is not approriate. A ≪derive≫ dependency from A to B means that A can be computed from B, i.e. that A is in fact redundant. For example, interface RectangleMath with operations getSurface and getPerimeter can be computed from interface Rectangle with operations getLength and getWidth.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl Yes, unfortunately. <<derive>> seemed to be well suited from the wording since you derive a new version from the old one. But they explicitly bind that to a computation. So I stepped back to <<trace>>.

Comment: Stereotype metaclass names are written with a capital first letter. When applied to another element, written between guillemets, the first letter is in lowercase. It must be mentioned somewhere in the UML specs. :-)

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl Thanks for the fix! Hmm, probably there must be something. But then they added that in a newer version (i.e. 2.5). If you happen to find the according text feel free to post it :-)

Comment: UML 2.5.1, section 12.3.4: "Matching between the names of Stereotype definitions and applications is case insensitive, so naming stereotype applications with lower-case letters where the stereotypes are defined using upper-case letters is valid, although stylistically obsolete. For legacy reasons a tool may display stereotype names with the
initial letter in lower case even when defined in upper case."

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl Ah, thanks for noticing. I found that already in another post, but this one was posted before. Will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

EA supports this. See documentation of "Time aware models" here:

https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/13.0/model_domains/time_aware_models.html

Allows maintaining separate versions of each package

Comment: Well, this looks promising. This answer should have more attention.